# Why does heroku give me this "incompatible type" error?

Tags: java, heroku, buffer, bytebuffer, discord-jda

I am trying to deploy my discord bot on Heroku.com, however i recieve a strange error...
Here's the code of the class that throws the error:

```
package main.Events.lavaplayer;

import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.AudioPlayer;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.MutableAudioFrame;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.audio.AudioSendHandler;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class AudioPlayerSendHandler implements AudioSendHandler {
    private final AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
    private final ByteBuffer buffer;
    private final MutableAudioFrame frame;

    public AudioPlayerSendHandler(AudioPlayer audioPlayer) {
        this.audioPlayer = audioPlayer;
        this.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        this.frame = new MutableAudioFrame();
        this.frame.setBuffer(buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canProvide() {
        return this.audioPlayer.provide(this.frame);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ByteBuffer provide20MsAudio() {
        return this.buffer.flip();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOpus() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This piece of code doesn't give me any problems while compiling with Intellij, but when i try to deploy it to Heroku they give me this error:

> error: incompatible types: java.nio.Buffer cannot be converted to @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable java.nio.ByteBuffer
> return this.buffer.flip();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`flip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip()) returns a `Buffer` rather than ByteBuffer so a cast is needed

```
public ByteBuffer provide20MsAudio() {
    return (ByteBuffer) buffer.flip();
}
```

Comment: You can't override the return type with a less specific type.

Comment: Though I'm curious, why the Intellij compiler didn't mark this as an error and compiled everything just fine?

Comment: Eclipse (which has its own compiler) complained. IntelliJ is probably not as strict on return types...